# Chi^2-Test for contingency tables larger than 2x2

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, contingency-tables, frequency

**Setting**

People were requested to make a yes/no-decision in overall 8 conditions. Hence, I have a 8x2-contingency table (per condition amount of yes and no decisions).

**Aim**

I want to check whether there are differences between those conditions regarding decision behavior.

**Question**

Can I apply $X^2$-test here or is $X^2$-test restricted to 2x2 contingency tables? Should I pick another test?

***PS:***

If necessary, it is possible to split data in 4-4 condition, resulting in 4x2 and 4x2 contingency tables.

Comment: The relevant Wikipedia article has: [Pearson's chi-squared test: Testing for statistical independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test#Testing_for_statistical_independence) ... "*...Each observation is allocated to one cell of a two-dimensional array of cells (called a contingency table) according to the values of the two outcomes. If there are $r$ rows and $c$ columns in the table ...*"

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing about the chi-squared test of independence (/homogeneity of proportion) that limits it to $2\times 2$ tables. It applies to rectangular tables of any larger size, or indeed of higher dimension.